# Replace a*b**N by a*pow(b,N)

Tags: regex, vim

I have an awful large expression that expresses the power in terms of the `**` operator and need to convert it to code that uses the `pow` function. That is, I look for a regular expression for finding and replacing terms like `a*b**N*d` by `a*pow(b,N)`, where `N` is an integer.

Here, `a`, `b`, and `c` are terms that may contain `xy*-+()` and integers and `a*`, `*d` may not be present.

I am somehow stuck with escaping all these characters. I am ready to invest some manual postprocessing, so the regex should be robust but not necessarily perfect.

EDIT: As Kent pointed out, there is a difficulty when `b` contains nested brackets. In my case there are no nested brackets. The terms are all of the form as given in the comment below.

Comment: does it mean `a+(i+(x*(m-n))+j)**p` will be converted into `a+pow( (i+(x*(m-n))+j),p)` ?

Comment: I feel that this is not the job for regex...

Comment: Yes. However, the terms rather look like `4*y**2*(-2*x + 1)*(-y + 1)**2` . What do you suggest?

Comment: it can be solved easily if there is maximum one pair of parens surrounding the term, without nesting -- see my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this problem cannot be solved generally by regexes, because you need to balance parens somehow -- and this is the task for a parser.

Something like this will do the job where the are no parens:
`%s/\(x\|y\|\d\+\)\*\*\(\d\+\)/pow(\1,\2)/gc`.

And something like this, if there may be only one pair of parens surrounding the term:
`%s/\(([xy0-9+-\* ]\+)\|x\|y\|\d\+\)\*\*\(\d\+\)/pow(\1,\2)/gc`

BTW it reminds me of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) question a bit =)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you can try using regex grouping to isolate the categories to extract:

So this is the regex:

`(a\*)(b)\*{2}(N)\*d`

You can extract the groups like so:

```
\1pow(\2,\3)
```

The reference groups are:

```
\1 = (a\*)
\2 = (b)
\3 = (N)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

Regex:`(\([0-9xy*-]+\)|[0-9xy]+)\*\*([0-9]+)`

Replace With:`pow($1,$2)` or `pow(\1,\2)`

Comment: K, it works! I only had to omit the plusses and escape the (). But that might be due to the vim 'magic'.

Comment: this won't work for nested brackets. e.g. in my comment. @Jan you should clearly define, what case in your real file, what not.  btw, vim has `very magic` which could save some escapes.

Comment: Mmm. Sorry for that. I don't have nested brackets in my expressions.